# output the record by comparing string in other file using awk script

Tags: awk

I want to output the record having matching string in another file using awk script 
file1 code

```
849002|48|1208004|1
849007|28|1208004|1
855003|48|1208004|1
855004|28|1208004|1
855006|28|1208004|1
```

file2 code :

```
00990029000000004804470425|ST1400029|0.550|Recurring|1248073|ST1400029
00990029000000008410517183|IM1450029|1.000|Recurring|855003|ST1400029
009900290000000000007800612988|IM3350029|1.000|Recurring|1248063|ST1400029
```

Notice that `855003` occurs in the middle row of each sample? That's the match I'm looking for, and the output should be:

```
00990029000000008410517183|IM1450029|1.000|Recurring|855003|ST1400029
```

Because I want to search $1 of file1 in $5 in file2, if match found then output the line 
I tried this but its returning zero record

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$1;next}a[$5]{print $0}' file2 file1  > outfile
```

Your help will resolve my issue, I have to search long list of data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't forget to set the delimiter using the `-F` flag:

```
awk -F "|" 'FNR==NR { a[$1]; next } $5 in a' file1 file2
```

Results:

```
00990029000000008410517183|IM1450029|1.000|Recurring|855003|ST1400029
```

Comment: @Rakesh: Don't forget to accept the answer if it has worked for you. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

try this (didn't test)

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}$5 in a' file1 file2
```